# Accumulator version of recursion

Tags: haskell

I have a example of accu version of recursion. 
Normal recursion:

```
fib n = if n== 0 then 1 else if n==1 then 1 else fib(n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

Accu recursion:

```
fib n fibPOM n 1 1 
fibPOM n f1 f2 = if n ==1 then f1 else fibPOM (n-1) (f1+f2) f1
```

And i must do the same with this(a^n recursion):

```
ff a n = if n==0 then 1 else if n==1 then a else a * ff a (n-1)
```

But i have no idea what i must do to get a^n accu recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint: add an accumulator argument `acc`

```
ff a n = ffACC a n (some initial accumulator value)

ffACC a n acc =
    if n==0      then ...
    else if n==1 then ...
    else  ...
```

Make sure that in each `...` all the recursive calls are tail calls. That is, return `ffACC (new a) (new n) (new acc)`, not something like `value * ffACC ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You start with an initial value 1: `ff a n = ffAccu a n 1`, then call the recursion as

```
ffAccu a n m = if n == 0 then m else (ffAccu a (n-1) (a*m))
```

(Note: The `if then else` construct might be written more cleanly by using pattern matching, as in

```
ffAccu a 0 m = m
ffAccu a n m = ffAccu a (n-1) (a*m)
```

)